# Unable to Apply Custom Authorization Policy with [Authorize] Attribute in Blazor Component

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a Blazor application, and I'm trying to apply a custom authorization policy using the [Authorize] attribute to allow anonymous access to certain components. However, I'm encountering issues with this setup, and the authorization policy doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here's what I've done so far:

In my Program.cs, I've defined a custom authorization policy using AddAuthorizationCore in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.AddAuthorizationCore namespace:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAnonymousAccess", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            // Allow anonymous access by returning true
            return true;
        });
    });
});
```

1. In my Blazor component (e.g., "Register.razor"), I'm trying to apply the "AllowAnonymousAccess" policy using the [Authorize] attribute:

```
@page "/Register"
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "AllowAnonymousAccess")]

<!-- The rest of your page/component content -->
```

However, despite these configurations, the authorization policy doesn't seem to allow anonymous access, and I'm still getting authorization errors.

Am I missing something in my setup or misunderstanding how to apply custom authorization policies in Blazor? Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

The error I keep getting is

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met: DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user

And I have tried using @attribute [AllowAnonymous].

Comment: Which error exactly are you getting? Status code 401 by any chance? Also, have you considered using [`[AllowAnonymous]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) instead?

Comment: @Xerillio Yes I have and i keep getting 

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user

Comment: I believe using `[Authorize]` requires you to be authenticated **before** any policies are applied, which explains that error. Are you saying you get the same error with `[AllowAnonymous]`?

Comment: Thanks for that information, but i don't think thats the case. 

@Xerillio Im back to an older solution where I use a eventcallback for now.

Are you saying you get the same error with [AllowAnonymous]? - Yes

Comment: use `[AllowAnonymous]` but setup another plain HttpClient with no tokens etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Authorize" and policies are used to further restrict and control what an already authenticated user can do.  As the wording would suggest it is an "authorization" mechanism, not an "authentication" mechanism and authorization (what you can do) happens after authentication (who you are).

If you want a page that is available without authentication (a public page) then you should simply need to make sure that page is not under a component that enforces authentication, like AuthorizeView's Authorized tag.  My guess (and I can only guess without seeing more of your project) is that your content is in a hierarchy similar to this:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <NotAuthorized>
        // Redirect to sign-in, etc.
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized>
        // Your content is somewhere under here
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Make sure to check the entire hierarchy of where your content is.  For example if your page uses a layout (a @layout directive), check the layout contents, etc.